Print Invoice A6
I want to print an invoice in A6 size. I’m using the following CSS for printing:
@media print {
    body {
        background: none;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .invoice {
      width: 105mm;
      height: 148mm;
      padding: 15mm;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .invoice-header h1 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .items th, .items td {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .total p {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .invoice-footer {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    @page {
        size: A6;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .invoice {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
}

However, in the print view, I see some alignment issues. The invoice layout is not displaying as expected. Could you suggest a solution to adjust the layout for A6 invoice printing?
The currently used printer is printing invoices in A6 size correctly, without any errors. The print settings are configured to the following dimensions: 80 (72.1) * 297 mm.


I don't understand the dimensions: "80 (72.1) * 297 mm". The 297 mm is the height of an A4, but the first two number I can't place. It looks like you're printing on the wrong paper size.
